# Edit Image Before Upload

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, canvas, html5

[image]

I have a requirement like after choosing the file there should be a section below that for edit purpose so that i can crop the image and a button should be there to replace the original file with the edited one. How can i achieve this any links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box from salesforce. But you can get many JavaScript pluggins to do that with cross-browser support. I have once used jcrop to do this. Jcrop is the one of quick and easy way to add image cropping functionality to your web application.

Jcrop - http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

> Here is a working demo code using Jcrop

VF page

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="SaveImage" >
    <apex:form >
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jcrop/0.9.12/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="target" class="crop" src="#" alt="your image" style="border:1px solid;display:none;"  />
        <canvas id="preview" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid; overflow:hidden;display:none;"></canvas><br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Image" onclick="saveImage();return false;" />
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas,fileName;
        $("#imgInp").change(function(){
            console.log(this);
            readURL(this);
        });
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                $("#target").css("display", "block");
                $("#preview").css("display", "block");
                fileName = input.files[0].name;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
                        $('#target').Jcrop({
                            onChange : updatePreview,
                            onSelect : updatePreview,
                            aspectRatio : 1
                        });                    
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        function updatePreview(c) {
            if(parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                // Show image preview
                var imageObj = $("#target")[0];
                canvas = $("#preview")[0];
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(imageObj, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        };
        function onSaveResult(result, event) {
            alert('File was saved as: '+result);
        }
        function saveImage(){
            var p1 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").match(/data:(.+);base64,(.+)/);
            console.log(p1[2]);
            {!$RemoteAction.SaveImage.saveImage}(fileName, p1[1], p1[2], onSaveResult);            
        }    
    </script>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class SaveImage {
    @RemoteAction public static Id saveImage(String name, String contentType, String data) {
        System.debug('name '+name);
        System.debug('contentType '+contentType);
        System.debug('data '+data);
        Document d = new Document(Name=name, FolderId=UserInfo.getUserId(), contentType=contentType, Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(data));
        Database.insert(d, true);
        return d.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a small demo of your work please

Comment: I will try to update the answer with a n example.

Comment: Any update on the example?

Comment: Can you please update the answer :)

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry to open this Issue again, Saroj Your Solution is working perfect and i am using that with little bit of modification instead of remoting i approached javascript method to get the values. But problem is when selecting different image after selecting the first one second image is not coming and first loaded image is deleted, i tried using destroy method of Jcrop but no luck Do you have any solution for that ? Thanks for your time @Saroj Bera